# Can't switch over to another window in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I've reorganised my question.

I have a two windows(in two different .py files) in one project built on Tkinter:

1. Login/Security UI which takes login and password. There is a "Login"
   button linked to the class' method which checks the name/pass pair
   and returns True if login data is correct
2. Main app UI.

So the problem is : after entering the correct username and password and pressing the button "Login" (this part works just fine, becouse i'm getting into correct IF section and method returns True) which supposed to call a Main UI window i got nothing happened. After closing manualy the Login window the second `Tk()` object (UI window) appears.

My code of Login UI:

```
class Security:
    def __init__(self):
        # -------- Window arrangement ------------------- #
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("Gym Activity Tracker")
        self.root.minsize(600, 300)
        self.user_name = StringVar()
        self.user_pass = StringVar()

        # --------- Login labels ---------- #
        self.user_label = Label(text="User: ")
        self.user_label.grid(column=0, row=1, pady=(20, 5))
        self.password_label = Label(text="Password: ", padx=50)
        self.password_label.grid(column=0, row=2, pady=(0, 10))
        self.info_label = Label(text="(Optional)", anchor="e")
        self.info_label.grid(column=2, row=2)

        # --------- Login Buttons ---------- #
        self.login_button = Button(text="Login", width=25, command=self.security_check)
        self.login_button.grid(column=1, row=3)

        # --------- Login Entries ---------- #
        self.user_name_var = StringVar(self.root)
        self.user_name_var.set("Choose an User")
        self.user_drop_list = OptionMenu(self.root, self.user_name_var, "sdf")
        self.user_drop_list.config(width=24)
        self.user_drop_list.grid(column=1, row=1, pady=(20, 5))
        self.password_entry = Entry(width=30)
        self.password_entry.grid(column=1, row=2)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def security_check(self):

        """Method validates the user's name and password (if applied) entered
        and returns True if security check has been passed"""
        user_name_entered = self.user_name_var.get()
        user_password_entered = self.password_entry.get()

        data = pd.read_csv("settings/users_list.csv")
        database_user_pass = data.loc[data.name == f"{user_name_entered}", "password"]
        if (f"{user_name_entered}" in data["name"].values) and (str(database_user_pass[1]) == user_password_entered):
            return True and self.root.destroy()

        elif f"{user_name_entered}" not in data["name"].values:
            tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(
                title="Username error",
                message="User does not exist. Please check a spelling or create a new user"
            )
            return False

        elif str(database_user_pass) == user_password_entered:
            tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(
                title="Password error",
                message="Password is not correct for this user"
            )
            return False

        else:
            print("Something went wrong with Security Check")
            return False
```

Which runs from main.py :

```
from frames.security import Security
from frames.ui import MainInterface


def main():
    authorization = Security()
    if authorization.security_check():
        app = MainInterface()
```

Functionality of Security/Login window works well.
Functionality of Main UI windows works well too.

How to make a programm to close the Security/Login window and run another `Toplevel` window? After executing the `self.root.destroy()` command in security_check function i get the tkinter error `can't invoke "destroy" command: application has been destroyed`

Comment: Are you creating more than one instance of `Tk`? Unless you understand why not, you should only create a single instance, and use `Toplevel` for other windows. The error you show is typical of an app that creates more than once instance of `Tk`.

Comment: When the line `if authorization.security_check()` is executed, the root window and its child widgets have been destroyed, that's why you get the exception.  You can associate a tkinter `StringVar` to the `password_entry` and use that variable to get the input password instead.

Comment: When appropriate, share the minimum amount of code others need to reproduce your problem ([also called a minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))  This would help others to help you

Comment: You should debug you application step by step. After the mainloop in security, your application will not reach the next steps in main.py until you close your application.

Comment: @BryanOakley i have replaced all instances of `TK` by `Toplevel` except one but still doesn't work for me.

Comment: Looks like the problem with Exception raised was solved by adding two StringVar objects (each one for name and pass). 
But still remained a problem to close Login UI window and open Main UI window. After pressing the "Login" button no exceptions raises, but Login window keeps on screen without any reaction. 
`.destroy()` method doen't work in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommended to call `mainloop()` inside `__init__()`.  Create another class method for this.

Also you should return the login status from the above-mentioned class method and don't call `security_check()` again as it is already called when <kbd>Login</kbd> button is clicked.  You should destroy the login window inside `security_check()` when the login is successful.

##### frames/security.py

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
import pandas as pd

class Security:
    def __init__(self):
        # -------- Window arrangement ------------------- #
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("Gym Activity Tracker")
        self.root.minsize(600, 300)
        # instance variable for login status
        self.login_passed = False
        self.user_name = StringVar()
        self.user_pass = StringVar()

        # --------- Login labels ---------- #
        self.user_label = Label(text="User: ")
        self.user_label.grid(column=0, row=1, pady=(20, 5))
        self.password_label = Label(text="Password: ", padx=50)
        self.password_label.grid(column=0, row=2, pady=(0, 10))
        self.info_label = Label(text="(Optional)", anchor="e")
        self.info_label.grid(column=2, row=2)

        # --------- Login Buttons ---------- #
        self.login_button = Button(text="Login", width=25, command=self.security_check)
        self.login_button.grid(column=1, row=3)

        # --------- Login Entries ---------- #
        self.user_name_var = StringVar(self.root)
        self.user_name_var.set("Choose an User")
        self.user_drop_list = OptionMenu(self.root, self.user_name_var, "sdf")
        self.user_drop_list.config(width=24)
        self.user_drop_list.grid(column=1, row=1, pady=(20, 5))
        self.password_entry = Entry(width=30)
        self.password_entry.grid(column=1, row=2)

        # don't call mainloop() inside __init__()

    def run(self):
        self.root.mainloop()
        return self.login_passed

    def security_check(self):

        """Method validates the user's name and password (if applied) entered
        and returns True if security check has been passed"""
        user_name_entered = self.user_name_var.get()
        user_password_entered = self.password_entry.get()

        data = pd.read_csv("settings/users_list.csv")
        database_user_pass = data.loc[data.name == f"{user_name_entered}", "password"]
        if (f"{user_name_entered}" in data["name"].values) and (str(database_user_pass[0]) == user_password_entered):
            # set login status to successful
            self.login_passed = True
            # destroy the login window
            self.root.destroy()
            return True

        elif f"{user_name_entered}" not in data["name"].values:
            tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(
                title="Username error",
                message="User does not exist. Please check a spelling or create a new user"
            )
            return False

        elif str(database_user_pass) != user_password_entered:  ####
            tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(
                title="Password error",
                message="Password is not correct for this user"
            )
            return False

        else:
            print("Something went wrong with Security Check")
            return False
```

###### main.py

```py
from frames.security import Security
from frames.ui import MainInterface


def main():
    authorization = Security().run()
    if authorization:
        app = MainInterface()
```

Comment: Thank You. That works. Yesterday i've figure out how to deal with `.destroy()` exception by placing `.destroy()` in separate func and calling it together with `security_check()` by lambda func, but got another problem insead with closing the Login window when `messagebox` error displays. But with Your code works just good.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not exactly sure on how to fix your issue but instead you could try to use '''
sys.exit(1)
'''
after you exit out of the UI